# Symfony2.8 Assetic - asset version not applied to url

Tags: twig, symfony, assetic

I seen similar questions here but none of them not working for me.
In addition these are old questions for older symfony2 version (different parameters). This can also happen in symfony3.

---

I need query version parameter to my production JS and CSS assets to avoid using old files. (by users ofc) For now generated asset looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/56a0cb5.js"></script>
```

In my template:

```
{% javascripts  '@XBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' 
                '@XBundle/Resources/public/js/ga.js' 
                '@XBundle/Resources/public/js/somejs.min.js'
                '@XBundle/Resources/public/js/main.js'  %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

And now also I added some lines in configuration file [according to documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#version):

```
framework:
    assets:
        version: 'v2'
        version_format: '%%s?ver=%%s'
```

but still my asset url looks the same.

**How can I achieve this?**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/56a0cb5.js?ver=v2"></script>
```

Thank you

Comment: have you clearing the cache in prod env ?

Comment: Yeah, clearing dev cache, prod cache and dumping assets - I think everything...

Answer (score 0):

You could declare version in templating section of framework like this:

```
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        packages:
            js:
                version: 'v2'
                version_format: '%%s?version=%%s'
```

In template:

```
{% javascripts  '@XBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' 
            '@XBundle/Resources/public/js/ga.js' 
            '@XBundle/Resources/public/js/somejs.min.js'
            '@XBundle/Resources/public/js/main.js' package='js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: How `package` works-  any docs? and why my docs say about `asset`, not templating - where is difference?

Comment: Extracted from here: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component 
And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795200/symfony2-assets-versioning-by-file
This will work until Symfony 3.0 and your code seems fine. It should work.

Comment: unfortunately this do not work :( your example is for Symfony 2.6 or lower. In addition i checked links and I tried newer version - using asset property and still nothing.